# Generic usb-serial device continuously gives 1`

Tags: linux, serial-port, ftdi

I'm trying to communicate with a [Di245](http://www.dataq.com/products/di-245/) through its Virtual COM driver (VCD) in Linux ([pdf](http://www.dataq.com/resources/pdfs/support_articles/DI-245-protocol.pdf)) and I'm having a strange issue. Internally, an FTDI chipset is used by this device (FT232BL).

Attaching the device by itself isn't registered as a VCD, so I do the following:

```
sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x0683 product=0x2450
```

which results in the following `dmesg` message:

```
usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
usbserial_generic 3-3:1.0: The "generic" usb-serial driver is only for testing and one-off prototypes.
usbserial_generic 3-3:1.0: Tell linux-usb@vger.kernel.org to add your device to a proper driver.
usbserial_generic 3-3:1.0: generic converter detected
usb 3-3: generic converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

and I get the `/dev/ttyUSB0` device as promised. So far, everything seems ok.

However, if I open the port in my code, I get a bunch of `` 1` `` from it (alternating `1` and `` ` ``). Trying with `screen`:

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

I continuously receive `` 1` ``. This is definitely not something the device is sending and oddly enough, if I put a random baudrate, I keep getting the same thing.

Is this a way some error is being reported? What could be triggering this behavior and how can I address it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was the following:

```
# modprobe usbserial vendor=0x0683 product=0x2450
# modprobe ftdi_sio
# echo "0683 2450" >> /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/ftdi_sio/new_id
```

This way, the `ftdi_sio` driver knows which vendor/product to provide VCD for. The following udev rule (say, `99-di245.rules`) can automate this:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0683", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2450", RUN+="/sbin/modprobe ftdi_sio" RUN+="/sbin/modprobe usbserial vendor=0x0683 product=0x2450" RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 0683 2450 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/ftdi_sio/new_id'"
```

It is installed with:

```
$ sudo cp 99-di245.rules /etc/udev/rules.d
$ sudo udevadm control --reload
```

Comment: [Here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165845/20085) a udev-rule is shown for automating this.

Comment: @PeterPablo, thanks, I had put it in an `init.d` script, but a udev rule is obviously better.